# How to make subequations

Tags: equations, subequations

I need equation (1) followed by equation (1.a), (1.b), etc. But I am getting equation (1), then (2.a) (2.b), etc.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Result = X + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}Y 
\end{equation} 

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
X &= ab \\    Y &= cd 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico it worked. Why not adding this as answer?

Comment: Because the method in egreg's answer is far more general. `\addtocounter{equation}{-1}` is quite hackish in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{whatever}
\begin{gather}\tag{\ref{whatever}}
\mathrm{Result} = X + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}Y
\\
\begin{align}
X &= ab \\    Y &= cd
\end{align}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Note how you can get the right vertical spacing instead of using `equation` and `align` with `align` nested in `gather`.

[image]

It's the same with `llncs`.